# How to set nuxt static page rendering with bootstrap and scss

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, static-pages, bootstrap-vue

I am currently merging a project from server-side rendering to static page rendering. According to the docs since nuxt 2.13 You can set the target to static inside of nuxt.config and run nuxt generate. This is correctly generating an html file for each file within my pages folder, however my pages lack all the styles. I am not sure if this behavior is expected or if I am missing something. I am currently using scss and bootstrap for the project. Any help would be appreciated.